# How can I find the Least Common Multiple of two fractions?

Tags: c#

> Precondition: The fractions are expressed in simplest form and `denom != 0`.
>   Improper fractions are allowed.
>
> Postcondition: Returns the LCM (as a fraction) of the two fractions.

Using `System.Numerics.BigInteger` for my numerator and denominator.

This is what I currently have, but I think this works only for `BigInteger`...not my custom made `Fraction` class:

```
public static Fraction LCM(Fraction a, Fraction b)
        {
            Fraction frac1, frac2;
            if (a > b)
            {
                frac1 = a; frac2 = b;
            }
            else
            {
                frac1 = b; frac2= a;
            }

            for (Fraction i = new Fraction(); i < frac2; i = i.Add(new Fraction()))
            {
                if (frac1.Multiply(i).Divide(frac2).Simplify().num == 1)
                {
                    return i.Multiply(frac1);
                }
            }
            return frac1.Multiply(frac2);
        }
```

`new Fraction()` returns `1/1`

Fraction Class:

```
    public class Fraction
    {
        public BigInteger num, denom;
        public Fraction power, coef;

        public Fraction()
        {
            num = denom = 1;
        }

        public Fraction(BigInteger n)
        {
            num = n;
            denom = 1;
        }

        public Fraction(BigInteger num, BigInteger denom)
        {
            this.num = num;
            this.denom = denom;

            if (GCD(BigInteger.Abs(num), BigInteger.Abs(denom)) != 1 || (num > 0 && denom < 0)
                                                                    || (num < 0 && denom < 0))
            {
                BigInteger n = Simplify().num;
                BigInteger d = Simplify().denom;
                this.num = n;
                this.denom = d;
            }
        }

        public Fraction(BigInteger num, BigInteger denom, Fraction power)
        {
            Fraction n = new Fraction(num, denom);
            coef = new Fraction();

            this.num = n.num;
            this.denom = n.denom;
            this.power = power.Simplify();

            if (power.num != 1)
            {
                Fraction n2 = n.Pow(power.num);
                this.num = n2.num;
                this.denom = n2.denom;
                this.power = new Fraction(BigInteger.One, power.denom);
            }

            if (this.power.denom != 1)
            {
                Fraction n3 = SimplifyRadical();
                this.num = n3.num;
                this.denom = n3.denom;

                if (n3.coef != null)
                {
                    coef = new Fraction(n3.coef.num, n3.coef.denom);
                }

                if (n3.power != null)
                {
                    this.power = n3.power.Simplify();
                }
            }
        }

        public Fraction(Fraction n, Fraction power)
        {
            BigInteger newNum = n.num;
            BigInteger newDenom = n.denom;

            Fraction n2 = new Fraction(newNum, newDenom, power);

            num = n2.num;
            denom = n2.denom;
            this.power = n2.power;
            if (n2.coef != null)
            {
                coef = n2.coef;
            }
        }

        public Fraction Multiply(Fraction f)
        {
            Fraction product;

            if (power != null || f.power != null)
            {
                if (power == null)
                {
                    power = new Fraction(1);
                }
                if (f.power == null)
                {
                    f.power = new Fraction(1);
                }

                Fraction LCMPower = LCM(power, f.power);
                product = new Fraction(new Fraction(num, denom).Pow(power.Multiply(LCMPower.Reciprocate()).num).Multiply(new Fraction(f.num, f.denom).Pow(f.power.Multiply(LCMPower.Reciprocate()).num)), LCMPower);
            }
            else
            {
                product = new Fraction(BigInteger.Multiply(num, f.num), BigInteger.Multiply(denom, f.denom));
            }

            if(coef != null || f.coef != null)
            {
                if(coef != null && f.coef != null)
                {
                    product.coef = coef.Multiply(f.coef);
                }
                else if(coef != null && f.coef == null)
                {
                    product.coef = coef;
                }
                else if (coef == null && f.coef != null)
                {
                    product.coef = f.coef;
                }
            }

            return product;
        }

        public Fraction Divide(Fraction f)
        {
            return Multiply(f.Reciprocate());
        }

        public Fraction Reciprocate()
        {
            if (power != null)
            {
                return new Fraction(denom, num, power);
            }
            else
            {
                return new Fraction(denom, num);
            }
        }

        public Fraction Raise(Fraction p)
        {
            Fraction newP = p;

            if (p.num < 0)
            {
                Fraction n = Reciprocate();
                num = n.num;
                denom = n.denom;

                newP = new Fraction(BigInteger.Abs(p.num), BigInteger.Abs(p.denom));
            }

            if (power != null)
            {
                return new Fraction(num, denom, power.Multiply(newP));
            }
            else
            {
                return new Fraction(num, denom, p);
            }
        }

        public Fraction Pow(BigInteger p)
        {
            BigInteger newNum = num;
            BigInteger newDenom = denom;

            bool reverse = false;
            if (p < 0)
            {
                p = -p;
                reverse = true;
            }
            else if (p == 0)
            {
                return new Fraction();
            }

            if (power != null)
            {
                if (reverse)
                {
                    return new Fraction(newDenom, newNum, power.Multiply(new Fraction(p)));
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Fraction(newNum, newDenom, power.Multiply(new Fraction(p)));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < p; i++)
                {
                    newNum = BigInteger.Multiply(newNum, num);
                    newDenom = BigInteger.Multiply(newDenom, denom);
                }

                if (reverse)
                {
                    return new Fraction(newDenom, newNum);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Fraction(newNum, newDenom);
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsOne()
        {
            Fraction ONE = new Fraction();
            return num == 1 && denom == 1;
        }

        public bool IsZero()
        {
            Fraction ZERO = new Fraction(0);
            return num == 0;
        }

        public static List<BigInteger> PrimeFactorization(BigInteger Fraction)
        {
            BigInteger prime = new BigInteger(2);
            List<BigInteger> primesArr = new List<BigInteger>();

            while (Fraction >= prime * prime)
            {
                if (Fraction % prime == 0)
                {
                    primesArr.Add(prime);
                    Fraction /= prime;
                }
                else
                {
                    prime++;
                }
            }
            primesArr.Add(Fraction);

            return primesArr;
        }

        public static BigInteger GCD(BigInteger num1, BigInteger num2)
        {
            while (num1 != 0 && num2 != 0)
            {
                if (num1 > num2)
                {
                    num1 %= num2;
                }
                else
                {
                    num2 %= num1;
                }
            }

            if (num1 == 0)
            {
                return num2;
            }
            else
            {
                return num1;
            }
        }

        public static Fraction LCM(Fraction a, Fraction b)
        {
            a = a.Simplify();
            b = b.Simplify();

            Fraction num1, num2;
            if (a > b)
            {
                num1 = a; num2 = b;
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = b; num2 = a;
            }

            for (Fraction i = new Fraction(); i < num2; i = i.Add(new Fraction()))
            {
                if (num1.Multiply(i).Divide(num2).Simplify().num == 1)
                {
                    return i.Multiply(num1);
                }
            }
            return num1.Multiply(num2);
        }

        public static bool operator >(Fraction num1, Fraction num2)
        {
            return Comparison(num1, num2) > 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <(Fraction num1, Fraction num2)
        {
            return Comparison(num1, num2) < 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(Fraction num1, Fraction num2)
        {
            return Comparison(num1, num2) >= 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(Fraction num1, Fraction num2)
        {
            return Comparison(num1, num2) <= 0;
        }

        public static int Comparison(Fraction num1, Fraction num2)
        {
            Fraction newNum1 = new Fraction();
            Fraction newNum2 = new Fraction();
            newNum1.num = num1.num * num2.denom;
            newNum1.denom = num1.denom * num2.denom;
            newNum2.num = num2.num * num1.denom;
            newNum2.denom = num2.denom * num1.denom;

            if (newNum1.num < newNum2.num)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (newNum1.num == newNum2.num)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (newNum1.num > newNum2.num)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public Fraction Simplify()
        {
            bool nnum = false, ndenom = false;

            if (num < 0)
            {
                nnum = true;
                num = -num;
            }
            if (denom < 0)
            {
                ndenom = true;
                denom = -denom;
            }

            BigInteger divisor = GCD(num, denom);

            BigInteger numNew = num / divisor;
            BigInteger denomNew = denom / divisor;

            if (nnum)
            {
                numNew = -numNew;
            }
            if (ndenom)
            {
                numNew = -numNew;
            }

            if (power != null)
            {
                numNew = SimplifyPower().num;
                denomNew = SimplifyPower().denom;
                Fraction powerNew = SimplifyPower().power;
                return new Fraction(numNew, denomNew, powerNew);
            }

            return new Fraction(numNew, denomNew);
        }

        private Fraction SimplifyPower()
        {
            return new Fraction(Pow(power.num), new Fraction(BigInteger.One, power.denom));
        }

        private Fraction SimplifyRadical()
        {
            Fraction final = new Fraction();
            final.coef = new Fraction();

            List<BigInteger> pN = PrimeFactorization(num);
            List<BigInteger> pD = PrimeFactorization(denom);
            List<BigInteger> pNDupes = FractionOfDupes(pN);
            List<BigInteger> pDDupes = FractionOfDupes(pD);

            int index = 0;
            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < pNDupes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (pNDupes[i] >= power.denom)
                {
                    BigInteger pow = pNDupes[i] / power.denom;
                    BigInteger powLeft = pNDupes[i] - power.denom * pow;

                    final.coef = final.coef.Multiply(new Fraction(pN[position]).Raise(new Fraction(pow)));
                    final.num *= new Fraction(pN[index], 1, new Fraction(powLeft, 1)).num;
                    position += (int)pNDupes[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    final.num *= new Fraction(pN[index], 1, new Fraction(pNDupes[i], 1)).num;
                }
                index += 2;
            }
            index = 0;
            position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < pDDupes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (pDDupes[i] >= power.denom)
                {
                    BigInteger pow = pDDupes[i] / power.denom;
                    BigInteger powLeft = pDDupes[i] - power.denom * pow;

                    final.coef = final.coef.Divide(new Fraction(pD[position]).Raise(new Fraction(pow)));
                    final.denom *= new Fraction(pD[index], 1, new Fraction(powLeft, 1)).num;
                    position += (int)pDDupes[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    final.denom *= new Fraction(pD[index], 1, new Fraction(pDDupes[i], 1)).num;
                }
                index += 2;
            }
            final.power = power;
            return final;
        }

        private List<BigInteger> NumberOfDupes(List<BigInteger> a)
        {
            List<BigInteger> l = new List<BigInteger>();
            List<BigInteger> final = new List<BigInteger>();

            foreach (BigInteger el in a)
            {
                l.Add(el);
            }

            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
            {
                BigInteger ele = l[i];
                final.Add(1);
                l.RemoveAt(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < l.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (ele == l[j])
                    {
                        final[index]++;
                        l.RemoveAt(j);
                        j--;
                    }
                }
                i--;
                index++;
            }

            return final;
        }

        public void Print(bool printLn)
        {
            if (coef != null && !(coef.num == 1 && coef.denom == 1))
            {
                PrintHelper(coef);
                if (!(num == 1 && denom == 1))
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            }

            if (!IsOne() || coef == null)
            {
                PrintHelper(this);
            }

            if (power != null && !power.IsOne() && !IsOne())
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.Write("^");
                PrintHelper(power);
            }

            if (printLn)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }

        private void PrintHelper(Fraction n)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write("[");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.Write(n.num);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            if (n.denom != 1)
            {
                Console.Write("/");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.Write(n.denom);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.Write("]");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("]");
            }
        }

        public Fraction Add(Fraction a)
        {
            Fraction newNum1 = new Fraction(Multiply(new Fraction(a.denom, a.denom)).num, denom * a.denom);
            Fraction newNum2 = new Fraction(a.Multiply(new Fraction(denom, denom)).num, denom * a.denom);

            return new Fraction(newNum1.num + newNum2.num, denom * a.denom);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the `Fraction` class?

Comment: What's the question ? Is anything not working ? Do you want "int" instead of BigInteger ?

Comment: Hi @Holger. I'm trying to make it so that the user can input an arbitrarily large number as the `num` and `denom`. To do this, I used the `BigInteger` class

Comment: @Holger. Everything seems to be working except for the `LCM` function. My implementation of it only works for `int`s, not `Fraction`s, and I've been struggling to find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integer algorithm is right, but it's based on integer arithmetic, on the idea a division, sometimes results in a natural number, and sometimes in a natural number and a Rest. This is not possible with fraction. You can dived them as you want - you will always get a new fraction - there will never be a Rest.

So this algorithm is not applicable. I found a formula, that makes a conversion:

```
lcm(a/b, c/d) = lcm(a,b,c,d)/lcm(b,d). 

lcm(a,b,c,d)=lcm(lcm(a,b),lcm(c,d)).
```

So all together is

```
lcm(lcm(a,b),lcm(c,d))/lcm(b,d)
```

So you got 4 calls to the integer version of lcm, to do one lcm for a fraction.

Do not Modify your int-version of LCM.

The Fraction version would be

```
public static BigInteger LCM(Fraction a, Fraction b)
{
      return lcm(lcm(a.num, a.denom), lcm(b.num, b.denom))/lcm(a.denom, b.denom);
}
```

But this will only find least natural number common multiple. 
The result of lcm(1/4, 1/8) will be 1, not 1/4 as one may assume.